# GitHub V4 GraphQL API with Java using some GraphQL Java library (if available)

Tags: java, graphql, github-api, simplegraph

For the V3 Version of the API I found quite a few questions here on Stackoverflow.
There are also libraries available at https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/.

I'd rather use the V4 api because I intend to do an integration for the simplegraph open source project see https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/issues/5

For the V4 API i found the following links so far:

- https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/
- https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#the-graphql-endpoint
- https://api.github.com/graphql
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphql-java
- https://github.com/graphcool/get-graphql-schema
- https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#example-query
- https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-java/1-getting-started/
- http://graphql-java.readthedocs.io/en/v7/schema.html
- https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/657

It looks as a starting point a Schema definition like this one:

- https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/test/groovy/graphql/StarWarsSchema.java

would be helpful.

**Where can I get souch a graphql-java useable schema definition of the github V4 api?**

Would it be possible to somehow create this from the Json response of the

```
query {
  __schema {
    types {
      name
      kind
      description
      fields {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

query?

At http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/GitHub-GraphQL I am documenting my next steps.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking... Are you looking to replicate GitHub' schema in graphql-java? Or are you looking for a client library to consume GitHub API?

Comment: I would like to use GitHub API V4 from Java and was assuming graphql-java could be a useable tool for that. For the time being I am completly lost since the docs are mostly greek (or maybe ancient egypt) to me.

Comment: Not sure why, but literally no one seems to use the word _client_ when looking for a client... Anyway, see my answer for options

Comment: -java means client in the java world. -server means server.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong tool then. graphql-java is an implementation of the GraphQL spec. It's used for developing GraphQL servers in Java.

What you're looking for is a client. There's currently only 2 available, neither great but likely usable.

- [Apollo Android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) - Don't let the name throw you off, it's perfectly usable from normal Java
- [Shopify's Java gen](https://github.com/Shopify/graphql_java_gen) - Generates a Java client from the given schema, similar to wsdl2java. Requires Ruby.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. In fact I'd like to avoid any compiled/static code at all.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl I'm confused. You're then looking for a generic HTTP client? You send a query via HTTP and get JSON back.

Comment: See https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/blob/master/simplegraph-github/src/test/java/com/bitplan/simplegraph/github/TestGitHubSystem.java - the JsonSystem can do this already. I need the option to adapt to a specific schema now in creating the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Here: https://github.com/octokit/graphql-schema/blob/master/schema.graphql is the GitHub v4 API schema. You can use this schema with graphql-java library.